# Order of mutex locking

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

Are mutex locks given to the threads in the order they are called? So say we have three threads A, B and C and a mutex mtx. If A calls mtx.lock() first, then B and then C, does that mean that A will get the lock first, followed by B and then C. If not, how can I guarantee it?

Comment: This is a genuine question. A [mcve] would turn it into a _good_ question. (note: I think OP knows thread A will indeed get the lock first, the core of their question being the lock order over threads B and C.)

Comment: "A" will get the lock first, but no guarantees about the order of "B" and "C"

Comment: is there a way to enforce the order of B and  then C?

Comment: @Rishi Threads can register their order of arrival in a FIFO. When a thread wakes up ("C" for example), it checks if it is its turn. If not, it wakes up the thread at the head of the FIFO and sleeps again

Comment: Redesign the system to get rid of such temporal couplings i guess.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi what sort of structure or class can I use to do that?

Answer (score 4):

If more than one thread is waiting on a mutex, a waiting thread is selected. Do not assume a first-in, first-out (FIFO) order. External events such as kernel-mode APCs can change the wait order. - From MSDN, page about Mutex objects.

See link:
[Mutex Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: what can I use to guarantee the order in this case?

Comment: That link seems to be about some platform-specific mutex API.  But there's no indication that the asker is using anything other than standard C++ (i.e. `std::mutex`).

Comment: It's unspecified which thread will receive ownership of the mutex when the current owner unlocks the mutex (I mean std::mutex)

Answer (score 0):

I have got a simple example to demonstrate this, I create 3 tasks, which acquire a lock, print something and then finish waiting to be joined. You can play around with this, instead of setting the barrier(3) you can set it to (2) and let the task_a just run and let the other two fight over the locks.

I use the boost::barrier to ensure that none of them start as soon as they are created. The result is a undeterministic order and not FIFO. Different platforms will give you a different result. [A demo of it in action](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b224876c7673704)

```
std::mutex foo;
boost::barrier bar(3);

void task_a () {
  bar.wait();
  foo.lock();
  std::cout << "task a\n";
  foo.unlock();
}

void task_b () {
  bar.wait();
  foo.lock();
  std::cout << "task b\n";
  foo.unlock();
}

void task_c () {
  bar.wait();
  foo.lock();
  std::cout << "task c\n";
  foo.unlock();
}

int main ()
{
  std::thread th1 (task_a);
  std::thread th2 (task_b);
  std::thread th3 (task_c);
  th1.join();
  th2.join();
  th3.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How would you guarantee the fifo order in the above code?

Comment: You could use condition variables where once one thread finishes you signal the other to go and so on for the third.

Comment: I thought condition variables do not guarantee the order either? or would I have to implement my code in a certain way? so say threads th2 and th3 are both using a conditional variable to wait on th1, would th2 be guaranteed to be the next one executed

Comment: They dont, its the latter part of the approach, you wait on th1 so th2 is executed next. You could also use atomics where each thread sets a count and they execute when the particular count is set.

Comment: and then another conditional variable to wait on th2?

Comment: Yea, give it a go.